# increment contract value with console call on truffle / testrpc, variable is not persistent

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-invocation

What I want to do is make a smart contract which has a variable that can accrue value. I'd like to have it start off as `0`, and then increment it, while periodically checking to verify that my calls to increase the value have in fact been working.

Here's my very simple smart contract to achieve that:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

// This contract demonstrates a simple non-constant (transactional) function you can call from geth.
// increment() takes no parameters and merely increments the "iteration" value. 

contract Incrementer {
    uint iteration;

    function Incrementer() {
        iteration = 0;
    }

    function increment(uint count) {
        iteration += count;
    }

    function getIteration() constant returns (uint) {
        return iteration;
    }

}
```

However, it must be broken, or perhaps I'm not calling it in the right way, as you can see by my console output:

[image]

The execution environment I'm using is truffle.

The commands to compile were:

```
truffle compile --all
truffle migrate --reset
```

Then I fire up to `truffle console` to interact with it, after having started `testrpc` in another window.

The exact commands I've been using it call it have been:

```
Incrementer.deployed()

Incrementer.deployed().then(function(instance) { meta = instance; return meta.getIteration.call(); })
```

and alternatively:

```
Incrementer.deployed().then(function(instance) { meta = instance; return meta.increment.call(1); })
```

How can I get the value of `iteration()` to increase by calling `increment()`, and then outputting the result with `getIteration()`?

---

**EDIT:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the correct procedures, according to my experiments, is to call in this way:

```
Incrementer.deployed().then(function(instance) { meta = instance; return meta.increment(1); })
```

output looks like this:

[image]

verify in this way:

```
Incrementer.deployed().then(function(instance) { meta = instance; return meta.getIteration(); })
```

results in:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two things jump out and some style hints.

**First, and probably most important**

When you `return meta.getIteration.call()` the `.call()` part is redundant (but harmless). It's redundant because the contract function is marked `constant` and therefore will only run in the local machine, not network verified. It should work just as well (and the same) without `.call()`.

But, you get into trouble when you `.call()` the `.increment()` because you are explicitly saying you want the local execution, verification-free, read-only execution mode. Therefore, it doesn't submit a transaction to the network. Ergo, doesn't do what you expect it to do.

**Second**

You might get over the first hurdle and then run into the next. After you drop `.call()` things are going to shift into `sendTransaction()` mode deep down, and you'll get a `txnHash` instead of a return value. This is normal.

**Style**

I would write `public` in both functions to help form a habit in line with best practices. It's the default, so it won't change anything. Also, I would `return(bool success)` or `return(uint newCount)` for the benefit of other contracts.

Hope it helps.

**Update**

Consider:

```
var contract;
var counter;

Incrementer.deployed()
.then(function(instance) {
  contract = instance;
  return contract.increment(1);
})
.then(function(txnHash) {
  return contract.getIteration();
})
.then(function(response) {
  var counter = response.toString(10);
  console log("Counter says:", counter);
});
```

Just going freestyle, here, so I hope I didn't flub it.

Comment: I've tried it without the `.call()` on `increment`, and also `getIteration`, but it seems to return only the method signature, or some such thing, in that case. I've posted the console output under the recent edit to the OP. Please forgive me for my ignorance but I'm not sure what you mean by `return(bool success)`, could you maybe show me how that would look like as part of one of those functions? Anyway, thank you very much for these pointers, I really appreciate your advice.

Comment: `meta.getInteraction().then(...` and `meta.increment().then(...`

Comment: how about the answer I just posted? seems to work

Comment: Seems like you headed in the right direction. I added a thought to my original answer. Maybe gives you some ideas.

Comment: I tried to call that `Incrementer()` method to reset it to zero though, and that didn't work, is it that you can only call those kind of constructor methods once for some reason?

Comment: Yes. Constructor fires once and once only. It's not available.

Comment: aha, ok cool. Is that just like a general programming paradigm? That constructors only fire once, and that you can't call a method with the same name as the... what's the name- contract? or class or something

Comment: In Solidity, a constructor is a function with the same name as the contract and it fires once during deployment with the deployer paying the cost of execution. It's roughly similar to init() in other languages. No one can call it.

Comment: aha, ok cool, it's good to know that. do you perhaps happen to have a good, i.e. up to date, etc., resource on how to deploy a contract such as this one to ropsten? I've been trying unsuccessfully to push this one to there